# Getting a value from a TextView

Tags: android

I have looked on line but I haven't found the way to get this value from the textview

Error is: cannot resolve method ValueOf()

```
time_left = timeLeftNumber.valueOf() - 1;
```

.

```
    package com.example.sensational.timetopress;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class press_screen extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int time_left;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_press_screen);

    }

    //Create Timer


    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextView amountOfTaps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_of_taps);
            TextView timeLeftNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_number_tv);
            time_left = timeLeftNumber.valueOf() - 1;
            timeLeftNumber.setText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
```

Comment: what is the error???

Comment: @Lal I just put it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextView` doesn't have `valueOf()` method. You can make the following:

```
    TextView amountOfTaps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_of_taps);
    TextView timeLeftNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_number_tv);
    time_left = Integer.valueOf(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString()) - 1;
    timeLeftNumber.setText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use method `getText()` which returns a `CharSequence`:

```
time_left = timeLeftNumber.getText().toString();
```

In order to get an `Integer` value use

```
time_left = parseInt(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString(), 10) -1;
```

As it might throw a `NumberFormatException` (final version):

```
try {
    time_left = parseInt(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString(), 10) -1;

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle invalid numbers; set reasonable default value
    time_left = 0;
}
```

Comment: I do that but I want to - 1 to the result. I do time_left = timeLeftNumber.getText().toString() - 1; but it outputs that the operator '-' cannot be applied to java.lang.String @Trinimon

Comment: @SexyBeast: sorry, I was not completely ready: third version is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

time_left = Integer.parseInt(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString()) - 1;

Answer (score 0):

To get value from `TextView` you should use `getText()` method. It returns `CharSequence` that might be easily changed to `String`and then you have to convert obtained value to int like this

`time_left = Integer.parseInt(timeLeftNumber.getText().toString()`

This method might throw NumberFormatException if entered text is not a number so you should place this invocation inside try-catch block.